# The ConnectionString Property has not been initialized

Tags: c#

Am getting a runtime error "The ConnectionString Property has not been initialized ", when i "build" the project it didnt show an errors....

```
private void FrmPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        button4.Enabled = false;
       this.ProductsTableAdapter.Fill(this.ProductDataSet.Products);
        this.SalesTableAdapter.Fill(this.SalesDataSet.Sales);
        string cnString = null;
        cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\POS.mdb";
        conn = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error..", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
        txtVAT.Text = "";
        txtCash.Text = "";
        txtChange.Text = "";
        txtTotal.Text = "";
        SalesIDTextBox.Text = "";

    }
```

Comment: Where do you get that exception? You are using a table-adapter before you create the `OleDbConnection`, does that make sense?

Comment: is anywhere you are using `conn` before these line of code. Where did you declare this variable?

Comment: You are going to have to give us more information...

Comment: The error message is somewhat helpful, but it would be better to know the line that it failed on. Either by using the debugger or capturing the stack trace from the exception.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess based on the little information you provided that you are trying to fill the adapters before you have opened the connection. Try moving that code into the `try/catch` as well.

```
    string cnString = null;
    cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\POS.mdb";
    conn = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        // Now that the connection is open, it can be used below
        this.ProductsTableAdapter.Fill(this.ProductDataSet.Products);
        this.SalesTableAdapter.Fill(this.SalesDataSet.Sales);
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error..", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```